# How to Coexist Logback and Log4j in a Java Project

Tags: java, spring-boot, log4j, logback, spring-logback

my java project use log4j 1.x，and it's a strong dependency.

my log4j configuration like this:

```
log4j.rootLogger=INFO, Console

LOG_PATH=logs
#log4j.appender.Console=org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender
log4j.appender.Console=org.apache.log4j.DailyRollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.Console.DatePattern='.'yyyy-MM-dd
log4j.appender.Console.File=${LOG_PATH}/console.log
log4j.appender.Console.layout=org.apache.log4j.EnhancedPatternLayout
log4j.appender.Console.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss.SSS Z} %p [%c{1}] [Thread-%t] %m%n
```

I have an other module `task-exec` use logback SiftingAppender to print log to different files. and I add `task-exec` module to my project, it work will.

my logback configuration like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration debug="false" scan="true" scanPeriod="60 seconds">
    
    <property name="CHARSET" value="UTF-8"/>
    
    <property name="PATTERN_DEF" value="[%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss SSS}] [%-5p] [%thread] [%logger{50}] [%M:%line] - %m%n"/>
    
    <appender name="console" class="ch.qos.logback.core.ConsoleAppender">
        <encoder>
            <charset>${CHARSET}</charset>
            <pattern>${PATTERN_DEF}</pattern>
        </encoder>
        <target>System.out</target> <!-- System.out|System.err -->
    </appender>
    <appender name="log_classify" class="ch.qos.logback.classic.sift.SiftingAppender">

        <discriminator>
            <key>MDC_LOG_FILE</key> 
            <defaultValue>other.log</defaultValue> 
        </discriminator>
        <sift>
           <appender name="${MDC_LOG_FILE}" class="ch.qos.logback.core.FileAppender">
                <file>${MDC_LOG_FILE}</file>
                <maxFileSize>20MB</maxFileSize>
                <encoder>
                    <charset>${CHARSET}</charset>
                    <pattern>${PATTERN_DEF}</pattern>
                </encoder>
            </appender>
        </sift>
    </appender>
    <logger name="mdcTaskLogger" level="info" additivity="true">
        <appender-ref ref="log_classify"/>
    </logger>
</configuration>
```

now, I want to add spring-boot-starter-data-jpa into the project. and I found that spring bean's logs will not output, only print a springboot banner.

I modify spring properties file like application.properties, but it is not work.

I add logback-spring.xml into jvm classpath, but it is also not work.

I add system property -Dlogback.debug=true, it only print `task-exec` load configuration, nothing about springboot.

```
21:44:50,299 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.core.joran.spi.ConfigurationWatchList@301434fb - URL [jar:file:/usr/lib/task-exec-1.3.33-SNAPSHOT.jar!/logback.xml] is not of type file
21:44:50,305 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.classic.joran.action.ConfigurationAction - Will scan for changes in [jar:file:/usr/lib/task-exec-1.3.33-SNAPSHOT.jar!/logback.xml]
21:44:50,306 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.classic.joran.action.ConfigurationAction - Setting ReconfigureOnChangeTask scanning period to 1 minutes
21:44:50,306 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.core.joran.action.AppenderAction - About to instantiate appender of type [ch.qos.logback.core.ConsoleAppender]
21:44:50,306 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.core.joran.action.AppenderAction - Naming appender as [console]
21:44:50,306 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.core.joran.action.NestedComplexPropertyIA - Assuming default type [ch.qos.logback.classic.encoder.PatternLayoutEncoder] for [encoder] property
21:44:50,307 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.core.joran.action.AppenderAction - About to instantiate appender of type [ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.RollingFileAppender]
21:44:50,308 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.core.joran.action.AppenderAction - Naming appender as [rolling_file]
21:44:50,308 |-INFO in c.q.l.core.rolling.TimeBasedRollingPolicy@1231160694 - No compression will be used
```

Can logback and log4j really not coexist?

how can I modify the configuration, can make them coexist?

my springboot version 2.7.13, logback version 1.2.12

my `task-exec` use logback version is also 1.2.12

my main project log4j version is 1.2.17